# Capture mouse click while animating an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm trying to animate a div and change its background color when the users clicks on it.

This is a sample code:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $("#one").hover(function() {
                $("#one").stop().animate({
                    top: -200
                }, 300);
            }, function() {
                $("#one").stop().animate({
                    top: 0
                }, 300);
            });
            $("#one").click(function() {
                $("#first").css("backgroundColor", "green");
                $("#second").css("backgroundColor", "green");
            });
        });
        </script>
        <style>
        #container {
            position:relative;
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        #one {
            position:absolute;
        }

        #first {
            background-color:blue;
            width: 200px;
            height:200px;
        }

        #second  {
            background-color:red;
            width: 200px;
            height:200px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="one">
                <div id="first"></div>
                <div id="second"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works, but it seems that the click event is not triggered until the animation ends.

A you can see [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B6gqA/), if you hover the element with the mouse and click on it while animating, nothing happens. If you wait for the animation to stop and click again, the mouse click will make the background change.

Is there a way to make javascript listen to clicks while animating?

Comment: Works fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/B6gqA/1/

Comment: @adeneo You changed the execution time. If you leave it 300, you'll see it's not working

Comment: How the hell do you click something within 0.3 seconds ?

Comment: ^^ and by that I mean, a click is a mousedown and a mouseup on the same element, you have two elements, so the mouse goes down on the first, and up on the second, as they move so fast, and that doesn't make it a click, as they are two different elements, even if you attached the event handler to the parent element, it still relies on bubbling, and it doesn't work when the events don't bubble from the same element. Does that explain it for you ?

Comment: Sidenote, listening for the mousedown or mouseup event only instead of click would work

Comment: @adeneo Yes it explains this. Is there a way to make it work? _How the hell do you click something within 0.3 seconds?_ It's called **testing**. A tester has to _test_ every possibility, including the most weird and impossible one. Testing this made the problem to come out and I want to solve it.

Comment: There's the mouseup event -> http://jsfiddle.net/B6gqA/4/

Comment: @adeneo Your solution works perfectly, can you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `click` event only happens when the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events happen on the same element, even if you're listening for the bubbling of the events on a parent element.

To solve it you can listen for just the `mouseup` event, which doesn't require there to be a `mousedown` event on the same element first.
The only drawback I can think of is that the `mouseup` event would also fire when the mousebutton is held down anywhere on the document, then dragged into the element and released, as that would also be a `mouseup` event, but that seems to be the point here, and probably not an issue.

```
$("#one").on('mouseup', function() {
    $("#first").css("backgroundColor", "green");
    $("#second").css("backgroundColor", "green");
});
```